# Поиск всех совпадений между двумя метками (PCRE verbs)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

## Задача:

С помощью регулярных выражений (PCRE) получить **все** совпадения текста между двумя заданными метками. Например - получить все **`КИРПИЧ`** между `КРЫША` и `ПОДВАЛ`, в строке может быть несколько интервалов `КРЫША`-`ПОДВАЛ`, посторонние предметы и кирпичи вне интервалов не нужны.

> КИРПИЧ ПОДВАЛ дверь **КИРПИЧ** дверь окно **КИРПИЧ** КРЫША труба КИРПИЧ

### Попытки решения

1) Опережающие и ретроспективные проверки - `(?<=)` и `(?=)`.

```
/(?<=ПОДВАЛ.*?)(КИРПИЧ)(?=.*?КРЫША)/g
```

**Проблема: ретроспективные проверки могут содержать квантификаторы, а опережающие - не могут.**

2) Backtracking control verbs - `(*PRUNE)`, `(*SKIP)`, `(*MARK)`, `(*THEN)`, `(*COMMIT)`. Вроде предназначены как раз для управления процессом обхода дерева вариантов. Пробовал сугубо методом тыка, не получилось из-за отсутствия толковых материалов на русском и детальных примеров. Выглядеть, наверное, будет как-то так:

```
/(^(?<!ПОДВАЛ).*?КИРПИЧ)(*SKIP)(*F)|(КИРПИЧ)(?=.*?КРЫША)/g
```

**Проблема: ловит некоторые кирпичи вне интервалов.**

## Вопрос

Подскажите, как использовать PCRE verbs для управления поиском. Приветствуются любые примеры, которые помогут понять принцип их работы (и использовать для данной задачи)

Comment: Первый раз слышу про такие расширения, надо будет почитать на досуге. Но вашу задачу решает такое выражение: `(?:ПОДВАЛ|(?!^)\G).*?(КИРПИЧ)(?=.*?КРЫША)` тест: https://regex101.com/r/pI9mN4/2  А что бы обычная проверка, поддерживающая произвольную длину считалась ретроспективной, например для замены гарантированно только кирпичей, можно перед кирпичем поставить \K и все что до нее будет ретроспективой

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за вариант. Для одиночных подвалов и крыш работает. А у вас нет решения, если такая конструкция встречается в тексте несколько раз? Для краткости приняв "подвал-кирпич-крыша"="этаж", нужно выбрать кирпичи только внутри "этажей", но не между ними.

Comment: Ну например так `(?:ПОДВАЛ|(?!^)\G).*?\K(КИРПИЧ)(?=(?(?=ПОДВАЛ)|.)*?КРЫША)` https://regex101.com/r/pI9mN4/3

Comment: О! Оно прекрасно в своей непонятности и рабочести) Получается из двух возможных путей решения вопроса "Рабочий lookbehind проверка" и "Backtracking control" вы помогли решить первым способом. Опубликуйте ответ - с радостью проголосую)

Comment: @Mike, кстати, вроде удалось сократить до `(КИРПИЧ)(?=(?(?=ПОДВАЛ)|.)*?КРЫША)` без потери функциональности

Comment: Ваш сокращенный вариант найдет кирпичи перед первым подвалом, если там не дай бог окажется неожиданная крыша. т.е. 'кирпич дверь крыша'

Comment: И мне кажется regex101.com не поддерживает verb. я тут почитал чуть чуть ... мне кажется перегруженную вопросами проверку отсутствия подвала можно было бы заменить на что то вроде `(ПОДВАЛ(*FAIL)|.)*`. проверять пока влом. потом как нибудь ... и то, если мой perl их поддерживает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот так](https://regex101.com/r/pI9mN4/3):

```
/(?:ПОДВАЛ|(?!^)\G).*?\K(КИРПИЧ)(?=(?(?=ПОДВАЛ)|.)*?КРЫША)/g
```

Основные моменты:

```
(?:ПОДВАЛ|        # Ищем ПОДВАЛ. Поиск в режиме глобального поиска работает только 1 раз
                  # так как при возврате Механизма для поиска следующего повтора
                  # он не помнит состояния, был подвал или нет
(?!^)\G)          # Поэтому ИЛИ ищем точку последней остановки поиска (но не в начале строки)
.*?\K(КИРПИЧ)     # собственно любые символы и искомая строка (\K не обязательна, но полезна при заменах)
 (?=              # подглядывание вперед (без захвата)
  (?              # Условие:
   (?=ПОДВАЛ)|    # Если ПОДВАЛ, то после скобки строка которую искать, а мы ничего не ищем
                  # поэтому условие становится отрицианием
    .)*?          # Иначе - подвала тут нет - берем любой символ, много раз, если есть
   КРЫША)         # а вот и добрались до крыши
```

[Вариант 2](https://regex101.com/r/pI9mN4/4), основан на предварительном захвате любых символов от начала строки до ПОДВАЛА и от КРЫШИ до следующего ПОДВАЛА (в полтора раза быстрее предыдущего):

```
(?>^.*?ПОДВАЛ|\G)(?(?=КРЫША).*?ПОДВАЛ|.)*?\K(КИРПИЧ)
```